# Autowire(XML) in Spring doesn't work for uppercase ids?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

This doesn't work:

### Triangle.java

```
public class Triangle {

    private Point PointA;

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Triangle draw.");
        System.out.println(getPointA().getX());
    }

    /**
     * @return the PointA
     */
    public Point getPointA() {
        return PointA;
    }

    /**
     * @param PointA the PointA to set
     */
    public void setPointA(Point PointA) {
        this.PointA = PointA;
    }

}
```

### spring.xml

```
<beans>
    <bean id="PointA" class="Point">
        <property name="x" value="0"></property>
        <property name="y" value="0"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "triangle" class="Triangle" autowire="byName" >
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This works:

### Triangle.java

```
public class Triangle {

    private Point pointA;

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Triangle draw.");
        System.out.println(getpointA().getX());
    }

    /**
     * @return the pointA
     */
    public Point getPointA() {
        return pointA;
    }

    /**
     * @param pointA the pointA to set
     */
    public void setPointA(Point pointA) {
        this.pointA = pointA;
    }

}
```

### spring.xml

```
<beans>
    <bean id="pointA" class="Point">
        <property name="x" value="0"></property>
        <property name="y" value="0"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "triangle" class="Triangle" autowire="byName" >
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Please note that the only difference between the above two examples are that pointA object has an uppercase "P" in one and lowercase "p" in the other. 
I find it strange how this could affect the auto wiring. Or is there some other problem altogether ?

Comment: My only guess would be that since you're not following JavaBeans conventions (`setPointA` is for a field/property named `pointA`), Spring might be getting confused. This style of configuration is ancient and best just not used in any case; Java-based configuration is nearly always better.

Comment: By confused you mean that it doesn't recognize the setter for `PointA` ?Also, can you explain this line again "This style of configuration is ancient and best just not used in any case; Java-based configuration is nearly always better."

Comment: You're not only using XML configuration, which is somewhat outdated, you're manually specifying the fields to set in XML instead of using `@Inject` or `@Autowired` on the class itself. Look at any references for "Spring Java configuration" for examples of code-based config.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at Spring documentation on the matter [Autowiring collaborators](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire), you can see that the *autowire by name* follows [JavaBeans convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions).

This is why the bean with `id` of `pointA` will be found and bean with `id` of `PointA` will not be, as the `Triangle` class has the property named `pointA` not `PointA`.

Comment: If you check closely, the `Triangle` class has property named `PointA` in the first case.

Comment: @Viraj and that does not make even the slightest difference, JavaBeans specification deals with how you name your getter and setter methods, and your bean `id` values are the one that differ and make the difference. Read the documentation carefully.